# Fade in one div, fade out all other divs, by clicking a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to create a webpage. The three top menu buttons open each new submenus. In the submenus I have buttons that need to open one div and close the others.

I have kind of successfully figured how to do that but the way I implemented it is very inefficient and I want to make it better. I found this http://jsfiddle.net/n53qg/ from stackoverflow which is pretty much what I want to do but for some reason can't get it to work. Even if I straight out copy paste all the HTML, CSS and JS to their respective files, linked the css and js + jquery to the HTML, it doesn't work. I'm baffled.

This is the way I implemented this: http://jsfiddle.net/mk92jtgz/6/ It takes a lot of work to add new divs so I need a way to close all the others in a simpler way.

EDIT: I'd like to understand why I can't get the copy-pasted code from jsfiddle to work in my own files. I would also respect some guidance on how to achieve what I have done in a more efficient way.

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
  $("#menu2").fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $("#menu3").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $("#menu1").fadeIn("slow");
    });
  });
  $("#button1").css("background-color", "white");
  $("#button3").css("background-color", "#f6c54e");
  $("#button2").css("background-color", "#f6c54e");
  currentDay();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see a question

Comment: Please consider adding some HTML to your question so we know what kind of elements these are, what classes or IDs they have, etc.

Comment: Fair enough. The question is what am I doing wrong not to get the jsfiddle code to work on my own files. OR if anyone has suggestions how to edit my code to achieve what I have already done but in a more efficient way.

Comment: Tyler Roper, I have included the jsfiddles with full code. Sorry if I don't get something. I'm new lol.

Comment: You should consider using a "tabs" plugin and just nest tabbed content inside of each other, as this is essentially what you're doing.